# Attempting to open html file on Chrome, always get a white screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, atom-editor

Good evening.
I'm learning JavaScript from scratch (really from nothing) and the course I'm learning from provided with html files to open in Chrome browser. When I attempt to open the files (via typing localhost:5000 and the file route, or opening it from Atom, or simply double clicking the file, it opens a tab in Chrome (in the title of the tab it says the file name) but in the tab window I only get a white screen. I'm using Atom editor as I said and node.js. Installed all the thingies (jasmine and such)
I know this is probably really easy to solve but I'm an absolute newbie at this. So, thanks in advance
P.S: sorry for my terrible English

Comment: What are the contents of the offending file?

Comment: It would be helpful to show screenshots, GIF, or using a service like Loom to show us what  you are doing to lead to the white screen.

Comment: May be try opening dev tool and see if there are any errors in that. Open your html file in chrome and press ctrl+shift+i. Another way is click on three dots of chrome window at top right corner -> More Tools -> Developer Tools

Comment: @superjisan This is the screenshot of the Chrome tab and the file opened in Atom
https://imgur.com/a/2H5cbrv
https://imgur.com/a/IipI4mA

Comment: @superjisan I've posted in the last comment the screenshots